# Using a column from inside a not in query

Tags: sql, db2

I have a sql query as below:

```
SELECT 
       A.COL1, A.COL2 
FROM 
       SOMESCHEMA.TABLE1 A
WHERE 
       A.COL3 NOT IN (SELECT A1.COL3 FROM SOMESCHEMA.TABLE2 B, SOMESCHEMA.TABLE1 A1 WHERE A.COL4 = B.COL4 AND B.DATE >= '2014-01-17')
```

The result of above query is two columns COL1 and COL2.

Now I want the DATE column of the second table into my result.

That is, the result should be COL1, COL2 and DATE.

How to achieve this?
Thanks for reading!

Comment: How does `table1` relate to `table2`?

Comment: @Linger: Through common column COL3.

Comment: @Linger: Have updated the query in the question.

Comment: then your `FROM` clause becomes `FROM TABLE1 A JOIN TABLE 2 B ON B.COL3 = A.COL3`. Change your `SELECT` to inclde the extra column from `B`.

Comment: @HughJones: Will that take care of my NOT IN condition ? and Table2 is not having COL3. Table1 and Table2 join on other column COL4

Comment: Is the relationship between table1 and table2 `one to one`?

Comment: @Linger: Table1 has four columns: COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 and Table2 has columns: COL4, DATE... Table2 joins with Table1 based on COL4.

Comment: @JChao: Yes. For every COL4 in Table1 there is a COL4 in Table2

Comment: Then user1245956 answer should work except Change the join on col4 and change >= to <

Comment: **@Vicky**, your query and what you are asking for does't make much sense.  Could you supply some sample data for both tables?

Comment: @Vicky - are we all missing the point?  Is it that you want to include the date that is in the `not in ..` clause?

Comment: So far, it doesn't make clear sense. Please include a few example rows from `TABLE1` and `TABLE2`, and show the result you want from the samples. The samples should include rows that match as well as ones that don't so we can determine the needed logic,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the situation you want to use a join:

```
SELECT 
      A.COL1, A.COL2, B.DATE
FROM
      SOMESCHEMA.TABLE1 A INNER JOIN SOMESCHEMA.TABLE2 B ON A.COL3 = B.COL3
WHERE B.DATE >= '2014-01-17'
```

You can find more info on using JOINS in DB2 here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_innerjoin.dita

Comment: Its NOT IN and not an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Your question as stated makes no sense - you're asking for matched data where the data does not match.  Sample data from each table and a sample output would really help here.

Here is my best guess as to what you're trying to do:

**Return data from Table2 where a match on COL4 exists that is greater than January 17th and has with a different COL3**

```
SELECT 
       A.COL1, A.COL2, B.DATE
FROM 
    SOMESCHEMA.TABLE1 A
     INNER JOIN 
    SOMESCHEMA.TABLE2 B ON 
        A.COL4 = B.COL4 AND
        B.DATE >= '2014-01-17' AND 
        A.COL3 <> B.COL3
```